# VBA Run Time Error 13 Type Mismatch #VALUE

Tags: vba

In some of my column's cells there appear `#VALUE!` words and formulas inside are as follows example:

```
=IF(VALUE(RIGHT(CELL("nome.arquivo";A1);LEN(CELL("nome.arquivo";A1))-SEARCH("]";CELL("nome.arquivo";A1))))=1;1;1+INDIRECT(ADDRESS(329;COLUMN();;;VALUE(RIGHT(CELL("nome.arquivo";A1);LEN(CELL("nome.arquivo";A1))-SEARCH("]";CELL("nome.arquivo";A1))))-1)))
```

Mentioned column is `CT`. Now when i am trying to loop through the cells when it comes to first occurence of #VALUE! i get an error:

`Run Time Error 13, Type mismatch` on this line:

```
 L = 9
         Do While Cells(L, "CT").Value <> ""         '<========= HERE AN ERROR
            L = L + 8
         Loop
```

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

<s>`Cells` doesn't take any `String` parameter, the type mismatch error you're getting has nothing to do with `#VALUE` / the data being processed - because the code never gets to evaluate the data, since `Cells` wants two `Integer` parameters:</s> dang this bites me everytime - apparently you *can* use string parameters in the `Cells` function. Ugh.

So the problem is with comparing the value to `""` - a string. `#VALUE!` isn't a valid string function so you need to account for it:

```
Dim theCell As Range
Set theCell = Cells(L, "CT")
If Not IsError(theCell.Value) Then
    Do While Not IsEmpty(theCell.Value)
        '...
        L = L + 8
    Loop
End If
```

You might also want to correctly qualify that function call:

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(L, "CT").Value)
```

That way it's *explicit* that you're looking at a cell *in the active worksheet*; an unqualified call is *implicitly* doing that, and anything implicit is potentially confusing and bug-prone.

Make sure the top of the module says `Option Explicit` and that `L` is properly declared:

```
Dim L As Long
```

"L" being a meaningless identifier, you should consider naming it after what you're using it for:

```
Dim currentRow As Long
currentRow = 9

Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow, "CT"))
```

That way your code becomes much easier to read, follow and understand.

Comment: `Cells` accepts two `Variant` parameters, and the second one can be a string (column letter in the `A1` notation). `Cells(L, "CT")` is a valid call.

Comment: @GSerg I know, I was in the middle of editing that out... bites me every time. gosh it's ugly though.

Comment: i tested all of your code and not working - also Type mismatch error. I found this way which looks its working fine: Do While IsEmpty(Cells(L, "CT").Value) . What do you think about my approach?

Comment: @JimmyJimm `Do While IsEmpty` is the complete opposite of what your original code is actually testing for. Stick a `Not` between the `While` and the `IsEmpty`.

Comment: Also it will bite you the minute you need to do something with that value. Best is to use `IsError` to verify whether the value represents an error value, *then* to do something with it.